# Error While Querying Azure DocumentDB

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Facing :

`GatewayProxy.java:performPostRequest:273:IllegalStateException: Http client execution failed`

I'm running a query to fetch all the documents ,Over which , some operation is done .

Any help on how this can be tackled ?

*EDIT*
Code :

```
  @Override
  public List<EmployeeRecord> fetchAllEmployeeRecords() {
    List<EmployeeRecord> employeeRecords = getAllDocuments();
    if(employeeRecords.size() > 0){
      return employeeRecords;
    }
    return null;
  }


  private List<EmployeeRecord> getAllDocuments(){
    String query = String.format(QUERY_FETCH_ALL_RECORD);
    List<Document> documents = documentClient.queryDocuments(getCollectionLink(), query, null).getQueryIterable().toList();
    List<EmployeeRecord> documentList = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(documents.toString(),employeeRecord);
    return documentList;
  }
```

Query :

```
private final String QUERY_FETCH_ALL_RECORD = "SELECT * from employeeRecord";
```

Comment: Please include the code.

Comment: @GauravMantri i apologise for the trouble .Have added code now .

Comment: @CruelEngine Could you post the details of your exception stacktrace log for helping analyze this issue?